# I want to have cell display the username I get from the http request, but It won't work. It just says that it can't find user in scope

Tags: swift, http

```
struct User: Codable{
    var id: String
    var username: String
    var password: String
    var profilepic: String
    var email: String
}



func getusers(userId: String) {
    
    let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/\(userId)")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            if let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data) {
                print(user)
            } else {
                print("Invalid Response")
            }
        } else if let error = error {
            print("HTTP Request Failed \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}


cell.name.text = "\(user.username)"
```

Comment: Yes because user can only be accessed in the if block where you are printing the user. If you want to access it outside the function create a user variable at instance level and then you can access it the way you are using it.

Comment: Move the line `cell.name.text = "\(user.username)` to right after the line `print(user)`. And the `URLRequest` is unused.

Answer (score 1):

As the error mentions, it is because `user` is out of scope when you are trying to use it.

In your code snippet, `user` is defined in an `if-let` block. It will only be available within that block of code. If you want to use it elsewhere, you will need to save it somewhere else.

Here is the official [Swift Programming Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html), I highly recommend that you read over it and familiarize yourself with basic coding principles Scope and Contexts.